# Doubt in using this is correct

Tags: grammar

Today my madam asked me inform to sir that she will come late l told to sir ....sir madam comes one hour late is this sentence correct which I used

Comment: I'm afraid I'm going to have to ask for some more context here.  Could you please provide the proper punctuation for this sentence?  If I read this aloud with no stops, I would almost suredly get confused looks.

Comment: Do not use the phrase "my madam," it sounds like you're referring to a "madam" in the sense of someone who runs a brothel.  Instead, use "madam" as if it was a name: "Today, madam asked me to...."

Answer (score 1):

It is idiomatic just to "be late",

> Sir, madam has asked me to inform you that she will be about one hour late

If you want to use a verb, then "arrive" is more appropriate than "come". The word "arrive" implies reaching a particular place, whereas "come" is more related to the journey.

> Sir, madam sends her apologies, she will be arriving an hour late.